# c++ passing a dynamic variable between 2 .cpp source files

Tags: c++, variables, dynamic

i have a variable that will be calculated in one of the source files during runtime and i wish to pass this calculated variable to another source file upon completion of the calculation. the calculation and the passing is a one-time thing. is this possible? thanks!

Comment: Of course it is possible. What have you tried up until now?

Comment: How is a value calcuated in a source file?

Comment: Passing variables between source files doesn't make sense. You pass variables to functions. You have to be more clear on what you want to do. There is some fundamental concept that you're misunderstanding here. If you show an example of what you would like to do, maybe we can help you correct that misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Declare that calculating function as `extern` inside a header file which `#include`ed by both the `.cpp` source file. And call that function wherever you want to access.

```
//file.h
extern int calculate();

//file1.cpp
#include"file.h"
int calculate()
{
  // logic
  return val;
}

//file2.cpp
#include"file.h"
int main()
{
  int i = calculate();
}
```

Comment: Unless one knows what Op is trying to acehive, the answer doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Why declare the function extern, if you include it?

Comment: @Hyperboreus, it's alternate syntax coming from C, extern word is optional there.

Comment: @unkulunkulu If we are talking about old school C, then "extern" is always optional (and hence senseless) with function prototypes. This is the whole sense of header files. Declare your functions there, define them somewhere else.

Comment: @Als, OP is calculating a variable inside one source file function and wants to access that value in another source file function. This is what I understood. He din't mention "function" word, but it's implied.

Comment: @iammilind what you're missing is that `extern int calculate()` is equivalent to `int calculate()` in a header file. Functions already have external linkage.

Comment: @iammilind: And for a moment if we remove the implied perception, we can see endless possibilities, it is not correct to speculate on an Q, it should be clear enough to be answered unambigiously, this one is simply not & an answer to an unclear Q cannot be possibly 100% correct, Secondly, Not my Downvote. I never downvote anyone's effort to help someone by answering.

Comment: @Karl, I understand that. I put this as my coding practice (just to mention that this function is `extern`ed)

Comment: +1: this is probably useful to gye325 (whether recognised as such or not), and shows the most useful general model for this kind of requirement.  `extern` is a non-issue - it iammiling uses it to indicate a non-inline function, then that seems as good as anything to me... might make sense in a coding style where there's lots of comments and prototypes at the top of the header, and some inline implementations below....

Comment: wow i did not expect this to turn into such a big discussion.
@iammilind: thanks for your answer. is it possible to just pass a variable value to the other function instead of creating a new function and returning it's value? 
i've tried implementing your answer but it appears that there are further complications because other variables that i need for the calculation are present in other functions and passing them seems to be another problem

Comment: @gye325, I have mentioned `calculate()` just as an example, you can modify according to your need like `calculate(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)` and so on, and also make the body change as `calculate(int, int, int, int);`